# SwiftUI: How to implement Edit menu in macOS app

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, swiftui-windowgroup

I am building a macOS-app using `SwiftUI` and the new `App` lifecycle.

All the default macOS menu items (like cut, copy, paste) are already there after starting a new project but they’re greyed out. **How can I implement methods for these default menu items?**

[image]

**Edit**: I am currently using `Xcode 12.2 beta 3` (12B5035g) on `macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 Beta` (20B5012d). I don’t want to solve this with Storyboards or within AppDelegate but instead with SwiftUI and the new `App` lifecycle.

Comment: Did you try to select some text and then select Copy? For me they work out-of-the-box so to say without any extra code. Or do you need copy some custom types?

Comment: You’re right, it works out of the box if I select the contents of a TextField for example. However I want to be able to run a custom copy function if no specific input field is focused.

Comment: You might want to clarify what version of macOS and Xcode you are using.

Comment: I just have clarified my original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the commands modifier, the CommandGroup and CommandMenu.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }.commands {
        // for example
        CommandGroup(replacing: .help) {
            Button(action: {someActionHere()}) {
                Text("MyApp Help")
            }
        }
        CommandMenu("Edit") {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I like this article. It explains a bit more. https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/11/24/commands-in-swiftui/

Comment: This will create a new menu called Edit, not allow implementing functionality for the existing Edit menu.