# Add application help under help menu in SwiftUI macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

If you open any app, it has the menu bar items on top with the last one being help. When I run my SwiftUI app for macOS right now and press help on the menu and then "(Application Name) help" it just says "Help isn't available for (Application Name)". How can I add support for this?

Comment: Are you using the SwiftUI lifecycle? Do you intend to use the standard help document format or display your own help view?

Comment: I am using the SwiftUI lifecycle and intend on using the standard help document format. However, I would also be curious on how to create my own view too for help simplicities sake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: How to implement Edit menu in macOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624369/swiftui-how-to-implement-edit-menu-in-macos-app)

Comment: Okay that answers 1 of the 2 questions about making a custom view for the help menu. How about if I wanted to adapt the standard document format?

Comment: Actually I've tried and I see that I can replace the help button with that but how do I display a view when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had answered my question a while ago after I found a workaround solution, however looks like I have not. To those looking for an answer here's a possible route you can take.

#### MyApp.swift

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var helpOpened = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .help) {
                Button(action: {
                    if !helpOpened {
                        helpOpened.toggle()
                        HelpView(isOpen: $helpOpened).openNewWindow(with: "Help")
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("MyApp Help")
                })
                .keyboardShortcut("/")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    private func newWindowInternal(with title: String) -> NSWindow {
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 320, height: 420),
            styleMask: [.titled, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .closable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.title = title
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        return window
    }
    
    func openNewWindow(with title: String = "new Window") {
        self.newWindowInternal(with: title).contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
    }
}
```

#### HelpView.swift

```
struct HelpView: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Help View")
                .padding()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            isOpen = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            isOpen = true
        }
    }
}
```

#### ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

When you run the application, you will find that pressing help and MyApp help button will launch that custom view.

You can use the following key command <kbd>⌘/</kbd> (<kbd>⌘?</kbd>) to open help as well.

Hope this helps :)